# Is memory released when a destructor is called or when `delete` is called?

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor

Assume you have an object of `class Fool`.

```
class Fool
{
    int a,b,c;
    double* array ;
    //...
    ~Fool()
    {
        // destroys the array..
        delete[] array ;
    }
};


Fool *fool = new Fool() ;
```

Now, [I know you shouldn't](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.5), but some fool calls the destructor on `fool` anyway.  `fool->~Fool();`.

Does that mean `fool`'s memory is freed, (ie a,b,c are invalid) *or* does that mean only whatever deallocations in `~Fool()` function occur (ie the array is deleted only?)

So I guess my question is, is a destructor *just another function* that gets called when `delete` is called on an object, or does it do more?

Comment: Perhaps worth pointing out that your class is dangerously underdefined; the destructor can only possibly be valid if you assign the result of `new char[]` to `array` at some point.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you write

```
fool->~Fool();
```

You end the object's lifetime, which invokes the destructor and reclaims the inner `array` array.  The memory holding the object is not freed, however, which means that if you want to bring the object back to life using placement new:

```
new (fool) Fool;
```

you can do so.

According to the spec, reading or writing the values of the fields of `fool` after you explicitly invoke the destructor results in undefined behavior because the object's lifetime has ended, but the memory holding the object should still be allocated and you will need to free it by invoking `operator delete`:

```
fool->~Fool();
operator delete(fool);
```

The reason to use `operator delete` instead of just writing

```
delete fool;
```

is that the latter has undefined behavior, because `fool`'s lifetime has already ended.  Using the raw deallocation routine `operator delete` ensures that the memory is reclaimed without trying to do anything to end the object's lifetime.

Of course, if the memory for the object didn't come from `new` (perhaps it's stack-allocated, or perhaps you're using a custom allocator), then you shouldn't use `operator delete` to free it.  If you did, you'd end up with undefined behavior (again!).  This seems to be a recurring theme in this question. :-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure your description is entirely symmetric. If I say `char buf[20000]; Fool * f = new (buf+17) Fool;`, then I can most certainly *not* call `operator delete(f);`. That's the whole point, allocation is unrelated to construction, and only she who fetched the memory can decide how to dispose of it.

Comment: @Kerrek SB- Ah, yes, that's true.  I was referring to the OP's question where the memory explicitly came from `new`, but you're absolutely right.  I'll go update my answer to mention this.

Comment: @Kerrek something about memory alignment springs to mind as I look at your example code

Comment: @Seth: Who says I didn't allocate `char pad[3];` just before `buf`? @template: On second reading, your assertion that the destructor "reclaims the inner array" is a bit optimistic - there's nothing in the OP's code that hints at how `array` is being used...

Comment: @Kerrek SB- I'm not sure I understand your last comment.  I said that the inner array is reclaimed because in the destructor, there's a call to `delete[]`.  I assume that this array was allocated properly.  Am I missing an important detail?  Or am I misinterpreting your last comment?

Comment: @Kerrek would that help? Someone told me that `char` arrays on the stack are not aligned for anything but `char` (could have been you, don't remember). `char pad[3]` would be a hit and miss, no?

Comment: @Seth Carnegie- Automatic arrays (arrays that are local variables) have no alignment guarantees, but all dynamically-allocated objects are guaranteed to be aligned in a way that anything can be constructed in them.  Though it should be `char pad[sizeof (Fool)]`. :-)

Comment: @template: Well, it's never said that `array` is being allocated with `new[]`, and only been allocated once, and not yet deallocated. This is probably what the OP has in mind, but I just wanted to point out that for all we know the destructor could be doing anything, and it really depends on the value of `array`. It's just a nitpick.

Comment: @templatetypedef wouldn't `char pad[sizeof(Fool)]` not help either since if `Fool` is say 8 bytes big and you're off by 2 on the stack as it is now, adding 8 bytes (`char pad[sizeof(Fool)]`) would just make you off by 6?

Comment: @Seth Carnegie- Whoops... I meant `new char[sizeof(Fool)]`.  Thanks for catching that!

Comment: @Seth: I'm just toying around. The idea was that 3+17 is a multiple of 4 and so hopefully usable for alignment of `Fool`, but ultimately I don't have to ensure any sort of alignment, do I? It's for me and my platform to know whether I can put `Fool` there or not. Just because the default `new` operator returns aligned memory doesn't mean I have to construct objects on any particular location...

Comment: @Kerrek I have no idea, I was under the impression that if you didn't align something properly (placement `new` in an automatic array), Bad Things would happen. And you didn't use default `new`, you used an array on the stack. I probably just missed something.

Answer (score 10):

The destructor call does just that, it calls the destructor. Nothing more and nothing less. Allocation is separate from construction, and deallocation from destruction.

The typical sequence is this:

```
1. Allocate memory
2. Construct object
3. Destroy object  (assuming no exception during construction)
4. Deallocate memory
```

In fact, if you run this manually, you will *have* to call the destructor yourself:

```
void * addr = ::operator new(sizeof(Fool));
Fool * fp = new (addr) Fool;
fp->~Fool();
::operator delete(addr);
```

The automatic way of writing this is of course `Fool * fp = new Fool; delete fp;`. The `new` expression invokes allocation and construction for you, and the `delete` expression calls the destructor and deallocates the memory.

Answer (score 3):

> Does that mean fool's memory is freed, (ie a,b,c are invalid) or does
>   that mean only whatever deallocations in ~Fool() function occur (ie
>   the array is deleted only?)

`Fool::~Fool()` has zero knowledge about whether the `Fool` instance is stored in dynamic storage (via `new`) or whether it is stored in automatic storage (i.e. stack objects). Since the object ceases to exist after the destructor is run, you can't assume that `a`, `b`, `c` and `array` will stay valid after the destructor exits.

However, because `Fool::~Fool()` knows nothing about how the `Fool` was allocated, calling the destructor directly on a `new`-allocated `Fool` will not free the underlying memory that backs the object.

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* access `a`, `b`, and `c` after the destructor is called, even if it's an explicit destructor call. You never know what your compiler puts in your destructor that might make those values invalid.

However, the memory is not actually freed in the case of an explicit destructor call. This is by design; it allows an object constructed using placement `new` to be cleaned up.

Example:

```
char buf[sizeof (Fool)];
Fool* fool = new (buf) Fool;  // fool points to buf
// ...
fool->~Fool();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest place to see that the destructor is distinct from deallocation via `delete` is when the allocation is automatic in the first place:

```
{
  Fool fool;
  // ~Fool called on exit from block; nary a sign of new or delete
}
```

Note also the STL containers make full use of the explicit destructor call. For example, a `std::vector<>` treats storage and contained objects lifetime quite separately.